# CSS External Link is not Working althouhg an internal link works

Tags: html, css, external-links

The external css link that I used is not working I tried using it inside the head tags it is working there. I have already tried;
-copying full path

```
-writing: type="text/css"
-writing: href="/css/styles.css"
-writing: href="css/styles.css"
-writing: href="styles.css"
```

[image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twvNb.jpg)
I would appreciate it if you can help

Comment: Don't post code as image. Copy and paste the code within the post itself. Make sure it's a [mre].

Comment: You have a spurious space in your href - linke din. This can be seen in the dev tools inspect stuff you have shown as only the first part of the url is underlined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

please remove `type="text/css"` .now it's working perfectly.